# javascript or jquery : mouse events

Tags: javascript, jquery

Need your help in understanding this code..Is this Javascript ( expression language ) or JQuery. I tried to understand but didn't get it.

```
var interval = 0, changed = false;
...............
...............

var start = function () {
    $(document).on('mousedown mousemove scroll touchstart touchmove keydown', change);
    setInterval(check, 1000);
};

 var change = function () {
    changed = true;
};

var check = function () {
   console.log("changed .....");
};

start();
```

Basically I want to do something ( business logic ) if user had performed some events on browser.Got this code on net and felt like something this is doing the same what i want.

Comment: Technically , `jQuery` is a `JavaScript` library written to make my and your life a lot easier.`$` is for `jQuery`

Comment: @harsha : Thanks.Can you please give me the idea what this script is doing.It will be helpfull for me to research of JQuery further

Comment: I have posted an answer trying to explain the example you have posted. Hope it helps you.Have a good day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var start = function () {
    $(document).on('mousedown mousemove scroll touchstart touchmove keydown', change);
    setInterval(check, 1000);
};
```

`$(document)` refers to your entire `HTML` document. [ON](http://api.jquery.com/on/) will attach an event handler function for one or more events to the selected elements. In your example , it'll attach the `mousedown mousemove scroll touchstart touchmove keydown` events to the `document` . Once any of those events occur , the `change` method gets called.

[setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval) is used to call a method repeatedly for the given duration.In your Example , it calls the `check` method every 1000ms or 1 second

Answer (score 1):

It's both. [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) is a Javascript library.

Answer (score 0):

This following part is jQuery specific, all other are pure JavaScript.

```
$(document).on('mousedown mousemove scroll touchstart touchmove keydown', change);
```

This is a event handler of jQuery which is calling a native javascript function `change()`.

***Notes:***

- To run the jQuery part you need to import jQuery Library from their site.
- You can identify the jQuery selectors by user of `$` infront. *(`$` does not always means jQuery)*

Comment: Thanks.Can we include JQuery in the servlet like we do for Javascript. Ex :  out.println("function getXMLHttpRequest() {");